# Не подключатеся mongoDB compass ( connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 )

Tags: mongodb, macos

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не могу подключиться к mongoDB compass, хотя сервер запущен [image: вот]

Comment: Первое впечатление - что создатели MongoDB прислушались к всеобщему плачу "что наши базы данных взламывают" и перестали их выставлять без авторизации со словами "заходи кто хочешь, берои что хочешь!". Монга то какая?

Comment: монгу устанавливал через brew (brew install mongodb-community) , последняя какая то

Comment: понятно, а как создавалась база? может, просто добавите в вопрос больше кода? Тогда - как толко можно будет воспроизвести проблему - я смогу попробовать у себя

Comment: я просто скачал монгу, поставил mongodb compass, нажимаю «connect» и ничего не работает, раньше все нормально работало.

Comment: вот как устанавливал: 1. xcode-select --install, 2.  /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)", 3.  brew tap mongodb/brew,
 brew install mongodb-community

Comment: Хм... как я понимаю, после установки монги нужно задать логин и пароль пользователя, который будет подключаться к базе. А потом те же логин и пароль дать "компасу" (ну, или любому клиенту, который захочет подключиться). Это было сделано? А, еще при установке надо как то сказать, должна ли монга слушать коннекты на интерфейсе 0.0.0.0. Вот там, где написано про successfully started - там должна быть еще инфа, про возможности подключения

Comment: а как задать этот самый логин и пароль?

Comment: Так, навскидку нагуглилась вот такая статья: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/ Надо  попробовать. Скорее всего, вопрос в том, как стартовать монго - демона, с какими параметрами. Возможно, это полностью решит Вашу проблему